# how to I make my responsive website look normal on galaxy s4 (media query)

Tags: css, media-queries

In order to code something that will fit my phones screen (galaxy s4) I usually have to code it in a manner in which it displays super big on my laptop screen. I have been looking into mediea querys and im pretty sure i have found the answer but am not sure how to apply it. Apparently the galaxy s4 has a pixel ratio of 3..? am i supposed to make a separate css sheet and link it? if so how would the mark up look? please supply a working example or atleast a link to the code. Thank you for your help. Im sure this is an easy fix i just cant figure it out for anything!...

Thanks again guys!
I really appreciate everyone's help.

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried? We have nothing to answer here.

Comment: What do i add to my mark up ?

Comment: @kleinfreund I want to know what i need to add to my css to make it compatible with my galaxy s4. 150px on my computer looks like 50 px on my phone..

Comment: You really should put up a specific question about a programming-related problem you're currently facing. Provide example code of your page (via http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: @kleinfreund how do i put this http://bjango.com/articles/min-device-pixel-ratio/ into my css?

Comment: I don't think you should start making a site responsive via the different pixel ratios. We can't help you here if you don't have a specific problem. You haven't tried something and searched for own solutions. Show some effort.

Comment: @kleinfreund really not helpful.. yes i am new to this.. Now i figured it out. why do you have to be so hard when the answer is so simple?

Comment: It's not helpful? Well, your question is not helpful. Not at all. We don't have any idea what you want, what you've tried to achieve at and so on. You provided nearly no relevant information and ignored the tips I gave you (Where is the demo?). I'm not hard to you. You're the one making it hard for us to answer.

Comment: It was on the same page as your link: https://gist.github.com/marcedwards/3446599, that will target all high density devices, however if you use fluid, responsive design css favoring percentages, ems, and rems you won't have issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check "media queries" it easy and nice
http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/
some sample
http://mediaqueri.es/

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to do responsive project and do device compatibility test, for Galaxy S4 I've used the following css code:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3.0) and (max-width: 1080px) {
    /* css for galaxy s4 here */
}
```

for more in depth look at why I formed my css for galaxy S4 this way: https://coderwall.com/p/ygcyha